# android vector background color transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-vectordrawable

My main layout look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.send.apk.bluetoothappsend.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_footer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I use following vector

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="1124dp"
        android:height="306dp"
         android:tint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:viewportWidth="11240.0"
        android:viewportHeight="3060.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M179,3046c-111,-20 -146,-55 -166,-170 -17,-96 -18,-1749 -2,-1861 18,-122 69,-172 194,-194 41,-7 417,-11 1126,-11 585,0 1168,-5 1294,-10 330,-14 760,-47 905,-70 415,-63 789,-207 1132,-437 277,-184 448,-251 718,-278 183,-19 297,-19 480,0 270,27 441,94 718,279 370,247 789,400 1238,451 462,52 862,65 2088,65 713,0 1090,4 1131,11 125,22 176,72 194,194 16,112 15,1765 -2,1861 -21,117 -54,150 -171,171 -100,17 -10778,17 -10877,-1z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#090b17"/>
</vector>
```

But problem that , there exists some black background as picture , I need trasparent background

[image]

Comment: Could you be using a dark background in the view containing your RelativeLayout?

Comment: not , I will attach all layout if you want

Comment: Then, perhaps are you using a dark theme in your app?

Comment: may be, how to solve this?

Comment: Check the android:theme attribute in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

Comment: Have you tried to replace the android:fillColor attribute with a different value, as suggested below?

Comment: Yes, t doesnt worked for me, But solution of Kamil Ibadov looks working

Answer (score 3):

First off, if you need a transparent view, you probably shouldn't even be using a vector image in the first place. But the issue is that you set your fill color to be `#090b17`, which should be `#00000000`.

Alternatively, you could set the background of your `RelativeLayout` to be:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.send.apk.bluetoothappsend.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_footer" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```